# Regex to match if . / - characters inside but only 1 next to each other

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need to create regex rule to match string with doesnt' contain `.` `/` `-` character and also strings that have them multiple times but not near them selfs.

Good strings (should be matched):

```
aaa/aa/aa
a/a.a
c.a
aaa-zz.z-ee/aa.z
```

Bad strings (there shouldn't be match):

```
aaa/aa/
z.zz//aa
zz..aa
fff//aa-a
zzzzz/
.
/
-
-aa
/aaa.
aasa....a
```

Tried and created sometithing like this `^[^\.\/\-\n]*(?:[\.\/\-])(?![\.\/\-])[^\.\/\-\n]*$` but it is finding also the `.aaa`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?!.*[./-]{2,})(?![./-])(?!.*[./-]$).*$/
```

- `(?!.*[./-]{2,})` lookahead to check that there are no two continuous evil characters
- `(?![./-])` lookahead to check that there is no evil character next to the start
- `(?!.*[./-]$)` lookahead to check that there is no evil character next to the end
- `.*$` match the whole string (not necessarily needed), change to `.+` if empty string is not allowed

https://regex101.com/r/xSTxiB/1

Comment: @Kornflexx you might post this as an answer. Note that it will not match empty strings, `a` or string containing characters that are neither `\w` nor `./-`

Comment: ok but your regex match with the sentence 'Bad strings (there shouldn't be match):'

Comment: @Kornflexx this sentence fulfills all requirements. It itself also isn't part of the bad strings but a mere description.

Comment: Do less possible. Good philosophy.